# Scipy sparse... arrays?

Tags: python, matrix, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

So, I'm doing some Kmeans classification using numpy arrays that are quite sparse-- lots and lots of zeroes.  I figured that I'd use scipy's 'sparse' package to reduce the storage overhead, but I'm a little confused about how to create arrays, not matrices.

I've gone through this tutorial on how to create sparse matrices:
http://www.scipy.org/SciPy_Tutorial#head-c60163f2fd2bab79edd94be43682414f18b90df7

To mimic an array, I just create a 1xN matrix, but as you may guess, Asp.dot(Bsp) doesn't quite work because you can't multiply two 1xN matrices.  I'd have to transpose each array to  Nx1, and that's pretty lame, since I'd be doing it for every dot-product calculation.

Next up, I tried to create an NxN matrix where column 1 == row 1 (such that you can multiply two matrices and just take the top-left corner as the dot product), but that turned out to be really inefficient.

I'd love to use scipy's sparse package as a magic replacement for numpy's array(), but as yet, I'm not really sure what to do.

Any advice?

Comment: See comments below, but I ended up just rolling my own sparse vector implementation, using something similar to a "dok" matrix.

Comment: The original question link seems to have died. @spitzanator.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use a `scipy.sparse` format that is row or column based: `csc_matrix` and `csr_matrix`.

These use efficient, C implementations under the hood (including multiplication), and transposition is a no-op (esp. if you call `transpose(copy=False)`), just like with numpy arrays.

EDIT: some timings via [ipython](http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/):

```
import numpy, scipy.sparse
n = 100000
x = (numpy.random.rand(n) * 2).astype(int).astype(float) # 50% sparse vector
x_csr = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(x)
x_dok = scipy.sparse.dok_matrix(x.reshape(x_csr.shape))
```

Now `x_csr` and `x_dok` are 50% sparse:

```
print repr(x_csr)
<1x100000 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
        with 49757 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

And the timings:

```
timeit numpy.dot(x, x)
10000 loops, best of 3: 123 us per loop

timeit x_dok * x_dok.T
1 loops, best of 3: 1.73 s per loop

timeit x_csr.multiply(x_csr).sum()
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.64 ms per loop

timeit x_csr * x_csr.T
100 loops, best of 3: 3.62 ms per loop
```

So it looks like I told a lie. Transposition **is** very cheap, but there is no efficient C implementation of csr * csc (in the latest scipy 0.9.0). A new csr object is constructed in each call :-(

As a hack (though scipy is relatively stable these days), you can do the dot product directly on the sparse data:

```
timeit numpy.dot(x_csr.data, x_csr.data)
10000 loops, best of 3: 62.9 us per loop
```

Note this last approach does a numpy dense multiplication again. The sparsity is 50%, so it's actually faster than `dot(x, x)` by a factor of 2.

Comment: +1 for plain numpy.dot. For kmeans, you want argmax( dot( k x N centres, each Nvec x )); the centres get dense anyway, so may as well keep them dense. (Averaging many sparse x s for new centres is very slow though.)

Comment: Well, if we put the multiplication speed aside, the OP might as well use `scipy.cluster.kmeans`...

Comment: Plausible. I prefer (advt)  [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529625/is-it-possible-to-specify-your-own-distance-function-using-scikits-learn-k-means), which can use any of the 20-odd metrics in scipy.spatial.distance; metric is more important for high-dim kmeans than algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a subclass of one of the existing 2d sparse arrays

```
from scipy.sparse import dok_matrix

class sparse1d(dok_matrix):
    def __init__(self, v):
        dok_matrix.__init__(self, (v,))
    def dot(self, other):
        return dok_matrix.dot(self, other.transpose())[0,0]

a=sparse1d((1,2,3))
b=sparse1d((4,5,6))
print a.dot(b)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the issue with that is that you have to transpose the dang things on the fly, which doesn't make a lot of sense when you're doing millions of comparisons.  I tried caching the dot products, but unfortunately, we don't do the same dot products very often, so that didn't help much.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that it is really much better or faster, but you could do this to avoid using the transpose:

```
Asp.multiply(Bsp).sum()
```

This just takes the element-by-element product of the two matrices and sums the products. You could make a subclass of whatever matrix format you are using that has the above statement as the dot product.

However, it is probably just easier to tranpose them:

```
Asp*Bsp.T
```

That doesn't seem like so much to do, but you could also make a subclass and modify the **mul**() method.

Comment: I also tried, for a vector [1, 2, 3], creating a matrix:

[1, 2, 3]
[2, 0, 0]
[3, 0, 0]

Taking two of these and multiplying (in any order) gives the desired dot product in the top left of the result matrix.  Unfortunately, this severely negatively-impacted speed.