# Do zero entries in numpy.array occupy memory?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, numpy, python-3.x, sparse-matrix

Suppose I use numpy arrays (e.g. `numpy.ndarray`) to store large, sparse matrices (i.e., most of the entries are 0): Do the zero entries actually occupy memory? Does numpy support sparse arrays, and if yes, which [storage format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Storing_a_sparse_matrix) is used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that what you are really looking for is the scipy sparse module, which supports multiple formats.

**SCIPY SPARSE DOCUMENTATION**
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html

The stackoverflow link below gives a great example of using scipy sparse matrices as well.
[Scipy sparse... arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540059/scipy-sparse-arrays)

Answer (score 3):

> Do the zero entries actually occupy memory?

With `ndarray`, they do.

There are, however, separate classes in SciPy that support a variety of sparse storage formats. See [the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html).

Comment: So sparse matrices are only in SciPy, not pure numpy?