# Gurobi model modification slow, can I modify the constraint matrix directly?

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, gurobi

I want to make changes to the coefficients in an existing model. Currently (with the Python API) I'm looping through the constraints and calling `model.chgCoeff` but it's quite slow. Is there a faster way, perhaps accessing the constraint matrix directly, in the Python and/or C API?

Example code below. The reason it's slow seems to be mostly because of the loop itself; replacing `chgCoeff` with any other operation is still slow. Normally I would get around this by using vector operations rather than for loops, but without access to the constraint matrix I don't think I can do that.

```
from __future__ import division
import gurobipy as gp
import numpy as np
import time
N = 300
M = 2000
m = gp.Model()
m.setParam('OutputFlag', False)

masks = [np.random.rand(N) for i in range(M)]
p = 1/np.random.rand(N)
rets = [p * masks[i] - 1 for i in range(M)]
v = np.random.rand(N)*10000 * np.round(np.random.rand(N))

t = m.addVar()
x = [m.addVar(vtype=gp.GRB.SEMICONT, lb=1000, ub=v[i]) for i in range(N)]
m.update()
cons = [m.addConstr(t <= gp.LinExpr(ret, x)) for ret in rets]

m.setObjective(t, gp.GRB.MAXIMIZE)
m.update()

start_time = time.time()
m.optimize()
solve_ms = int(((time.time() - start_time)*1000))

print('First solve took %s ms' % solve_ms)

p = 1/np.random.rand(N)
rets = [p * masks[i] - 1 for i in range(M)]
start_time = time.time()
for i in range(M):
    for j in range(N):
        if rets[i][j] != -1:
            m.chgCoeff(cons[i], x[j], -rets[i][j])
m.update()
update_ms = int(((time.time() - start_time)*1000))
print('Model update took %s ms' % update_ms)

start_time = time.time()
m.optimize()
solve_ms = int(((time.time() - start_time)*1000))
print('Second solve took %s ms' % solve_ms)

k = 2
start_time = time.time()
for i in range(M):
    for j in range(N):
        if rets[i][j] != -1:
            k *= rets[i][j]
solve_ms = int(((time.time() - start_time)*1000))
print('Plain loop took %s ms' % solve_ms)

R = np.array(rets)
start_time = time.time()
S = np.copy(R)
copy_ms = int(((time.time() - start_time)*1000))
print('np.copy() took %s ms' % copy_ms)
```

Output:

```
First solve took 1767 ms
Model update took 2051 ms
Second solve took 1872 ms
Plain loop took 1103 ms
np.copy() took 3 ms
```

A call to `np.copy` on the size (2000, 300) constraint matrix takes 3ms. Is there a fundamental reason I'm missing that the whole model update can't be that fast?

Comment: Could you update your question with an example model that demonstrates the slowness of the update operation?

Comment: @josilber I've added an example to roughly show what I'm trying to do.

Comment: You might want to try an [unofficial Gurobi API](https://github.com/supermihi/gurobimh), which is claimed to be faster. I have never checked it though. From the C API you can [change all coefficients of a row directly](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/6.5/refman/c_grbchgcoeffs.html).

Answer (score 4):

You can't access the constraint matrix directly in Gurobi using the Python interface.  Even if you could, you couldn't do an np.copy operation because the matrix is in the [CSR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540059/scipy-sparse-arrays) format, not a dense format.  To make the sort of wholesale changes to a constraint, it is better to modify the constraint matrix by removing the constraint and adding a new one.  In your case, the changes to each are so significant that you aren't going to get much benefit from a warm start, so you won't loose anything by not keeping the same constraint objects.

Assuming you adjust the `rets` array in the code above for the -1 special case,  the following code will do want you want and be much faster.

```
for con in cons:               
    m.remove(con)
new_cons = [m.addConstr(t <= gp.LinExpr(ret, x)) for ret in rets]
```

Comment: Thanks, even a CSR copy would be much faster than rebuilding all the constraints I would have thought. What about the C API?