# Get coordinates of a surface of revolution as a 3D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, geometry

I'm working on a small project in which the end goal is to obtain some surfaces of revolution generated from custom functions. This is an example representation for sin(x):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.seterr(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore')

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')



x = np.linspace(0,np.pi,600) # Setting the left and right boundaries for sin(x)
y = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi,600)
U,V = np.meshgrid(x,y)

def function(x): # This is where I would like to pass a random function, for now it's just sin(x)
    return np.sin(x)

a = np.vectorize(function) # Vectorizing it so I won't get the length-1 arrays converted to python scalars error
b = a(x) # Applied the function element-wise on the x array

X = U
Y = b*np.cos(V)
Z = b*np.sin(V)


ax.set_xlabel('Y axis')
ax.set_ylabel('X axis')
ax.set_zlabel('Z axis')

ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)

plt.show()
```

Giving me the sphere-shaped object that I expected: [Solid of revolution of sin(x)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0IGu.png)
Is there a way to convert the surface into a 600x600x600 numpy array for future use?

Comment: What would it mean to store the surface as a 3D array? Do you mean you want a voxelization of the volume?

Comment: Sorry for not being specific, but yes that's exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53016634/how-to-fill-3d-array-in-numpy-with-functional-values-at-the-same-speed-as-java